# Make element with MaxHeight take the whole space in the Grid if it's less than it's MaxHeight, otherwise pin to the bottom

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to accomplish the following:

- Have a badge on the right side of the `Grid` element.
- The badge should have a max height of 33px.
- If `Grid` height itself is less than 33px, the badge should take whole available space and be the same size as the `Grid`.
- If `Grid` height itself is more than 33px, the badge should be pinned to bottom and be 33px tall.

Here is the code that I have at this moment:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <!-- ... -->
   <Grid Grid.Column="2">
      <Border Width="60"
              MaxHeight="33"
              CornerRadius="0 0 3 0"
              Background="#FFD20B0B">
           <TextBlock FontSize="13"
                      FontWeight="Bold"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      FontFamily="Arial"
                      Foreground="#FFFFFFFF">
                  <Span>Broken</Span>
            </TextBlock>
       </Border>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This accomplished all requirements except the last one. Whatever I do, the badge is being pinned to the center if the parent `Grid` size is larger than 33px. How can I pin it to bottom in this case?

P.S. If I use `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"`, I'm losing the third requirement - badge does not become `Grid`'s height when `Grid`'s size is less than 33px (e.g. `Grid` size = 20px).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, WPF does not have a built-in XAML syntax for doing comparisons like *greater than*. What you could do is create a custom value converter for that, e.g. returning `true` if  a value is greater than a given parmeter and `false` otherwise.

```
public class IsGreaterThanConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (!(value is double doubleValue) ||
          !(parameter is string parameterText) ||
          !double.TryParse(parameterText, out var doubleParameter))
         return Binding.DoNothing;

      return doubleValue > doubleParameter;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

The idea is to bind the `ActualHeight` of the parent `Grid` in a `DataTrigger` that checks if it is greater than a threshold (here `33`) using the converter above. Depending on that, it sets the `VerticalAlignment` and the `Height` of the `Border`. The default value of `VerticalAlignment` is `Stretch`, which is set if the actual height is less than or equal to `33` (converter returns `false`).

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
      <local:IsGreaterThanConverter x:Key="IsGreaterThanConverter"/>
   </Grid.Resources>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <!-- ... -->
   <Grid Grid.Column="2">
      <Border Width="60"
              MaxHeight="33"
              CornerRadius="0 0 3 0"
              Background="#FFD20B0B">
         <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
               <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Converter={StaticResource IsGreaterThanConverter}, ConverterParameter=33}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Height" Value="33"/>
                     <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style> 
         </Border.Style>
         <TextBlock FontSize="13"
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Arial"
                    Foreground="#FFFFFFFF">
            <Span>Broken</Span>
         </TextBlock>
      </Border>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Do not forget that the converter needs to be instantiated in a resource dictionary in scope, here in the `Grid.Resources`. Of course you can extract the style to a resource dictionary, too, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the Height of the Border to the ActualHeight of the Grid. That combined with your MaxHeight and VerticalAlignment will give you what you're looking for.

```
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Grid.Column="2">
    <Border Width="60"
            MaxHeight="33"
            CornerRadius="0 0 3 0"
            Background="#FFD20B0B"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=RootGrid}">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Border>
</Grid>
```